# How to find images in lazyload to set alt attribute?

Tags: images

i am working the SEO of my website and decided to use lazyload on the images. Problem is that when you run f12 Google Audit, the report tells me that every lazyloaded images are missing the "alt atrtibute". The thing is i cant find the code to set the attribute. Where can i change it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress has multiple images in multiple locations. Those can be images inside of posts, featured images, icon images in menus, product images, logo image in header, images in footer for branding and many more. Therefore it is not possible to answer your question specifically with little details that you given.

Generally speaking you can use an SEO plugin such as Rank Math: http://rankmath.com/
It will allow you to add alt text to certain types of images.